# Can't precompile during heroku deploy due to unexpected token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, assets, precompile

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku and keep encountering the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
remote:        Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: name (rails)
remote:        /tmp/build_b36b00ce08c22f161edb02afae19ceef/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
remote:        /tmp/build_b36b00ce08c22f161edb02afae19ceef/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_b36b00ce08c22f161edb02afae19ceef/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_b36b00ce08c22f161edb02afae19ceef/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/compressing.rb:65:in `block in js_compressor='
remote:        /tmp/build_b36b00ce08c22f161edb02afae19ceef/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy_proc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_b36b00ce08c22f161edb02afae19ceef/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_b36b00ce08c22f161edb02afae19ceef/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
...
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
```

I have tried manually precompiling the assets using `rails assets:precompile` ad well as implementing the suggestions in the following github link:  https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/739

Comment: 2 questions: are you using ES6 in your JS and are you setting the ENV for production when you precompile (`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`)?

Comment: I don't believe I am using ES6.  I haven't added any javascript to the project except some dependencies that I was prompted to as part of adding bootstrap..
Other than that, there is no other javascript and it does not appear to be ES6.  And yes, I am declaring the env as production.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does changing this setting help? https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/116#issuecomment-347386669

Comment: I have already changed that setting.. no, it does not help :(